# Run while loop more than one time using the single query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there anyway to run php while loop more than one time ? For example if in a table have 6 rows in total and how can I show them twice so it will show 12 items instead ? I know I can do that by adding an other same query but I was just looking any short way to prevent duplicate codes.

Actually I have a slides section to show partners in a slides so as for now we have only few partners so we want to repeat partners slide.

Comment: I'm wondering why do you need to run the loop twice? The problem is when the data is coming from the database you can't simply run it twice without resetting the record pointer, better save your values in some array and then loop through that twice if you really need it. If you show some code and explain why you need it that would help solve your problem.

Comment: Some existing code you may help in finding the best solution.

Comment: show your actual code  ..

Comment: add the result set to an array - you can process that array repeatedly

Comment: I think `$mysqli_result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` will give you an Array of Associative Arrays. Store it in a var and reuse it. Note: unless doing a `->fetch_all()` you're just getting each row with each call.